# Having trouble with public class fields in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to import a javascript class ("vendor/test") from another file, and I'm getting an error (`error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =`). The reason I'm doing this is because I'm trying to edit an unmaintained library, and use it in my codebase.

Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields, the `field ="123"` seems to be simply a public class field and should be valid code, but it's throwing the above error. What am I missing?

File doing the import

```
import {Test} from '../../../vendor/test';
```

Second File

```
test.js
export class Test {
    field = '123';
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
        console.log('creating test');
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: On which line do you get that error?

Comment: What Node.js and Typescript versions are you running? What does your `tsconfig.json` look like?

Comment: I'm getting the error for the line `field = '123'. Oh, I don't have a tsconfig.json file, I saved this as .js. Is that the reason why it's not working?

Comment: Is this an error reported at runtime (by Node or the browser) or at compile time  (by Typescript)?

Comment: _"I don't have a tsconfig.json file"_... you probably should. You'll want to set an appropriate compiler target. Also, you didn't answer my question about Node.js

Comment: Thanks, my node version is v16.16.0. I'm not sure about my typescript version since I dont have a tsconfig.json file, I'll need to set it up.

Comment: Your Typescript version is not related to `tsconfig.json`. It's whatever you installed (should be in `package.json`)

Comment: I checked package.json, and it seems that typescript isn't installed. I guess that's probably the reason - I'll try installing and see if that fixes it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-resonance-kj2mq5?file=/src/index.js) and it works.

It shows an error saying as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError: /src/index.js: Unexpected token, expected ","...
```

But it fixes when I import `Test` as `default`, not naming import like `{Test}`. So you face this type of error because of using `export default` in the `test.js` file and `naming import` in the other file to import the class.

So you should use `import Test from "./test";` instead of `import {Test} from './test';`

Also, there are no errors using both `Test` and `{Test}` when I use `export class Test {...}` within `export default Test;` in the `test.js` file and `ts` version `4.4.4` in the `package.json` file as follows:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.4.4"
  },
```

The codesandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-resonance-kj2mq5?file=/src/index.js)

Hope this will help. Thanks!

[image: import export js file]